# diff two streams (using fifo's) up until one ends – only works for short streams

Tags: bash, diff, fifo

I would like a diff wrapper that I can use on arbitrary bash streams that only prints differences up until the line-length of the shortest. This is easy for regular files, simply read them twice:

```
~/bin/mindiff:
min=$(calc -p 'min(' $(wc -l < "$1") ', ' $(wc -l < "$2") ')')
diff <(head -$min "$1")  <(head -$min "$2")
```

(I find this really useful to check differences in text-processing output as they're running.)

***Note***: I do not want a diff on a line by line basis. I want exactly what the above script does (which allows diffs spanning multiple lines), but working on streams. I just don't want the mess at the bottom which results from one stream/file being longer than the other. I would prefer to call regular diff so that I can pass any regular diff options like -B1, -y --suppress-common-lines -W180, -U1 piped into dwdiff for fancy word-diffs with colours, etc.

However, I'd like to be able to call this on arbitrary streams, only reading them once, e.g.

```
mindiff <(sed 's/fluff//' /tmp/out) <(ssh server sed 's/fluff//' /tmp/out)
```

With the help of some #bash wizards, I got this awk helper which reads the two streams in parallel until one ends, and runs diff on that:

```
mkfifo a b

awk '
BEGIN{ f2=ARGV[2];ARGC-- }
( (getline line <f2)>0 ) { print > "a"; print line > "b" }
' "$1" "$2" &

diff a b
```

[Complete script](https://gist.github.com/unhammer/5728652#file-mindiff-sh)

It works for short toy examples, but if I try something like

```
mindiff <(yes |head -40000) <(yes |head -40000)
```

it just hangs. Adding a "print NR;" to awk shows it go up to line
36865 (while with `<(yes yesyes)` it goes to 10533, so it seems to be
allowing a certain number of bytes, regardless of number of lines).

Adding `system("")` to flush awk every line makes it stop even earlier
(line 34818).

What is blocking my diff?

UPDATE: My suspicion is that on running `diff a b` where a and b are big, diff will ask for a bunch of lines from a, then a bunch from b. Since the helper script only gives lines in parallel, it tries to push one line to a, then one to b, but diff is in the process of asking for more lines from a, so the push to b hangs. When doing a regular `diff <(cmd) <(cmd)` however, the first cmd can push a bunch of lines, while the second waits.

Comment: `cat <(yes |head -40000) <(yes |head -40000)` at least shows that it is a problem with `mindiff`.

Comment: Also, the length of FIFO #1 doesn't matter - Only FIFO #2's length changes which line it halts at.

Comment: By adding `print NR` before, between and after the `print` commands you can see that it is the `print line > of2` which fails.

Comment: Thanks to this question, I learnt a lot about pipes and their interaction with perl, Symbol tables in perl and the perl's lack of an inverse for `fileno`.

Comment: l0b0: "Only FIFO #2's length changes which line it halts at" – what do you mean? If you decrease at least one of the numbers (doesn't matter which), it runs fine, awk exits at the end of the shortest one.

Answer (score 1):

Altering the answer as per your clarification.

I would suggest you dump `awk` and use a `perl` script as your helper to do this job.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my ($f1 ,$f2)=@ARGV;

open(my $fifo1, '<', $f1) || die("Couldn't open file $f1: $!");
open(my $fifo2, '<', $f2) || die("Couldn't open file $f2: $!");

my $count=0;
while(not (eof($fifo1) or eof($fifo2)) ) {
    my $a = <$fifo1>; chomp($a);
    my $b = <$fifo2>; chomp($b);
    print "my_diffing_function(\'$a\', \'$b\')\n"; 
    # Alternatively write these lines to 2 fifos
    ++$count;
}
close $fifo1;
close $fifo2;
```

This allows you to define your own diff function to check line by line whether there is a difference or not. Or you could use [Text::Diff](http://search.cpan.org/~adamk/Text-Diff-1.37/lib/Text/Diff.pm) to do the same. Better still you could open 2 fifos to write to and let `diff` work on those fifos.

To test it, just do:

```
samveen@precise:/tmp$ perl differ.pl <(yes |head -n 20) <(yes 'n' |head -n 30)
my_diffing_function('y', 'n')
my_diffing_function('y', 'n')
my_diffing_function('y', 'n')
my_diffing_function('y', 'n')
my_diffing_function('y', 'n')
my_diffing_function('y', 'n')
my_diffing_function('y', 'n')
my_diffing_function('y', 'n')
my_diffing_function('y', 'n')
my_diffing_function('y', 'n')
my_diffing_function('y', 'n')
my_diffing_function('y', 'n')
my_diffing_function('y', 'n')
my_diffing_function('y', 'n')
my_diffing_function('y', 'n')
my_diffing_function('y', 'n')
my_diffing_function('y', 'n')
my_diffing_function('y', 'n')
my_diffing_function('y', 'n')
my_diffing_function('y', 'n')
```

You could open a pair of pipes for output from this helper script and write out to them, and spawn diff on the side on the pipes.

Comment: Updated the question a bit to clear the misunderstanding. I don't want line-by-line diffs, I want regular diffs. I just don't want the mess at the end caused by one file/stream being longer much longer than the other (typically they'll only differ a couple places every thousands of lines).

Comment: I guess I could learn how to reproduce the options I use the most in Text::Diff, but I'm trying to waste less of my time, not more =P also I would have to install a new dependency on every machine I use it on (BTW, isn't it a bit misleading to name those variables fifo in that perl script?)

Comment: And thirdly (fourthly? something), I'm very curious as to _why_ the fifo→diff script does not work …

Comment: @unhammer Altering to your specifications.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to simply parse diff output and remove the fluff at the bottom. This unfortunately seems the easiest. E.g. to deal with both -u and regular diff output:

```
diff "$@" "$if1" "$if2" | awk '
lines && /^@@ -[0-9]*,[0-9]* \+[0-9]*,[0-9]* @@$/ {print lines; lines=""}
lines && /^[0-9]+,[0-9]+d[0-9]+$/ {print lines; lines=""}
// {if(lines)lines=lines"\n"$0; else lines=$0}
'
```

Dealing with -y would require some more work. It's not a very satisfying solution.